# How get latest users - limited 10

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this CI project in which sometimes I need to manage to get latest users but limited 10 to display on dashboard,

for example if new one users joined than one of older user should remove on display dashboard.

because i want it limited 10 users to display on dashboard.

Comment: ok so.......... do LIMIT 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your user model put :

```
public function get_LastTen(){   

   $this->db->select("*"); 
   $this->db->limit(10);                        
   $query = $this->db->get("users");          
   return $query->result();            

}
```

Controller :

```
$this->load->model('user_model');      
$lastUsers =  $this->user_model->get_LastTen();   
$data['lastTen'] = $lastUsers;
```

And in your view :

```
    <?php for($i=0;$i<count($lastTen);$i++) { ?>
        <li><img src="user_image.jpg" alt="User Image"><a href="#"><?php echo $lastTen[$i]->user_name; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM Users LIMIT 10 ;